# How to add a line break in a multi line textbox in Visual Studio designer's property section

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, newline

This is a WinForm VB.NET application. Please see the picture below:

[image]

How to add a line break in a multi line textbox in Visual Studio designer's property section?

I tried using `abc & Environment.NewLine & def` but that was not working.

#### Update:

How to do that in VS 2008, VS 2005, and VS 2003?

Comment: Do you mean using the GUI? You cannot write code in the designer's property section. Why don't you add it in the initialization code?

Comment: @nadirs: Yes, using GUI for convenient.

Answer (score 6):

On the right side of the Text property there should be a DropDown Box (at least that's true for Visual Studio 2010), if you click that, you should be able to insert multi line text.

Or edit the .Designer file manually.

The designer generated code looks like this

```
Me.textBox1.Text = "AAA" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "BBB" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "CCC"
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just as described by @SchlaWiener

Comment: I was thinking about creating a screenshot, too. But I was to lazy for that ;)

Comment: Your answer was OK - it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **\r\n** in the properties box or **Environment.NewLine** in the code